# Why escaping backslashes are appear in ElasticSearch Nest Query?

Tags: c#, .net, string, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to write a C# method that get the `queryString` of a controller and converts it into an **ElasticSearch** query, like below:

```
public QueryContainerDescriptor<T> Convert<T> (IQueryCollection query) where T: class
{
    var selector = new QueryContainerDescriptor<T>();
    List<QueryContainer> Must = new List<QueryContainer>();
    foreach(var key in query.keys)
    {
        string value = query[key];
        var match = new MatchQuery { Field = $"{key}.keyword", Query = value };
        list.Add(match)
    }
    selector.Bool(q => q.Must(Must.ToArray()));
    return selector;
}
```

It works as expected, but if I pass a `queryString` value with a backslash, like:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/indexData?user=ESKA\\USER
```

It should be converted into this query:

```
{ "bool": { "must": [ { "match" : { "user.keyword": "ESKA\\USER" } } ] }
```

But **ElasticSearch** will return nothing because the value will of the query be: `ESKA\\\\USER` with 4 backslashes, like:

```
{ "bool": { "must": [ { "match" : { "user.keyword": "ESKA\\\\USER" } } ] }
```

how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Nest is performing any escaping of backslashes. Here's an example that writes out the requests (and responses, if using an `IConnection` that sends the request)

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri($"http://localhost:9200"));
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, new InMemoryConnection())
        .DefaultIndex("default_index")
        .DisableDirectStreaming()
        .PrettyJson()
        .OnRequestCompleted(callDetails =>
        {
            if (callDetails.RequestBodyInBytes != null)
            {
                var json = JObject.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(callDetails.RequestBodyInBytes));
    
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"{callDetails.HttpMethod} {callDetails.Uri} \n" +
                    $"{json.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented)}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{callDetails.HttpMethod} {callDetails.Uri}");
            }
    
            Console.WriteLine();
    
            if (callDetails.ResponseBodyInBytes != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Status: {callDetails.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                         $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(callDetails.ResponseBodyInBytes)}\n" +
                         $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Status: {callDetails.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                         $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
            }
        });
        
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
    
    var collection = new QueryCollection(new Dictionary<string, StringValues>
    {
        { "user", "ESKA\\USER" }
    });
    
    var response = client.Search<object>(s => s
        .Query(q => Convert<object>(q, collection))
    );
}

public static QueryContainerDescriptor<T> Convert<T>(QueryContainerDescriptor<T> selector, IQueryCollection query) where T : class
{
    List<QueryContainer> Must = new List<QueryContainer>();
    foreach (var key in query.Keys)
    {
        string value = query[key];
        var match = new MatchQuery { Field = $"{key}.keyword", Query = value };
        Must.Add(match);
    }
    selector.Bool(q => q.Must(Must.ToArray()));
    return selector;
}
```

the resulting query is

```json
POST http://localhost:9200/default_index/_search?pretty=true&typed_keys=true 
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "user.keyword": {
              "query": "ESKA\\USER"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If the `user` value were to be the [*verbatim string literal*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) `@"ESKA\\USER"`, then the resulting query would be

```json
"user.keyword": {
    "query": "ESKA\\\\USER"
}
```

because each `\` in the verbatim string literal needs to be escaped.